# Flutter test - Find by specific TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

How to find specific textfield on flutter test.

I would like to find specific textfield (for this instance email & password textfield) on widget testing `testWidgets` so I can test if it is existing on the UI or not.

login.dart

```
Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Email',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height:12),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Password',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

login_test.dart

```
Widget createWidgetForTesting({Widget? child}) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: child,
  );
}

testWidgets('find email textfield', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(createWidgetForTesting(child: const Login()));

    final emailTextfield = find.byElementType(TextField);// this;
    expect(emailTextfield , findsOneWidget);
});

testWidgets('find password textfield', (tester) async {
     await tester.pumpWidget(createWidgetForTesting(child: const Login()));
    
     final passwordTextfield= find.byElementType(TextField);// this;
     expect(passwordTextfield, findsOneWidget);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find by text by label like this:

```
    final emailField = find.ancestor(
      of: find.text('Email'),
      matching: find.byType(TextFormField),
    );

    await tester.enterText(emailField, "testing");
    expect(find.text('testing') , findsOneWidget);
```